# Failed to download the file in Codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter. From a ajax file i am calling a download controller.There I have written the code which i found in the net. But it is not starting download the file. I have created a **onreadystatechangefunction()** where I have a div call **myDiv**.

Now whenever I am clicking the download button it is showing only the content of the file not starting downloading. 
When I can **abort()** in **onreadystatechangefunction()** I got nothing.
I just want as soon as i click the download button it should start downloading the file which is not happening. Here is the controller code :

**PHP CONTROLLER**

```
    <?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Downloadfilefromserver extends CI_Controller
    {

        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));      
            $this->load->library('security');
            $this->load->library('tank_auth');  
            $this->load->helper('file');
            $this->load->helper('download');

        }   

        function index()
        {

            echo "welcome to downlaod a course index";
        }

        function pushFileFromServer()
        {
                $path = $this->input->post('dl_file_path');
            $file_name_in_server_arr = preg_split("/\\/uploads\\//", $path ); //also can be get by basename($path)
            $name= ($file_name_in_server_arr[1]);
            // make sure it's a file before doing anything!
            if(is_file($path)){
                // required for IE
                if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression')){ 
                    ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'off'); 
                }

                // get the file mime type using the file extension
                $mime = get_mime_by_extension($path);

                // Build the headers to push out the file properly.
                header('Pragma: public');     // required
                header('Expires: 0');         // no cache
                header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
                header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate ('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime ($path)).' GMT');
                header('Cache-Control: private',false);
                header('Content-Type: '.$mime);  // Add the mime type from Code igniter.
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($path).'"');  // Add the file name
                header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
                header('Content-Length: '.filesize($path)); // provide file size
                header('Connection: close');

                readfile($path); // push it out             

                //$data = file_get_contents($path); // Read the file's contents
                //force_download($name, $data); 
                exit();
            }
        }
}
```

**Javascript**

And here is the ajax code from which i am calling the controller:

```
   function downloadUploadedFile(dl_file_path,dl_file_name){

        var xmlhttp;                    
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }else{
                // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){ 
                    abort();
                     document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;       

                 }                  
        }             
        xmlhttp.open("POST","../downloadfilefromserver/pushFileFromServer",true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");                   
        xmlhttp.send("dl_file_path="+dl_file_path+"&dl_file_name="+dl_file_name);
   }
```

I want to add that my

```
xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200
```

is working.

Comment: you may have to use file api

Comment: i have googled  file api in codeigniter and got lot of links can you tell me more specific?

Comment: Are you per chance using XSRF protection and forgetting to send that token?

Comment: what does that mean @TimPost . I am a newbie in this. It will be great if you tell me what part of my code should be modified . If you need any other part code i can post it.

Comment: i got that you are talking about CSRF protection . No i have not set it true. In my config file :
$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't download a file using AJAX. Just make your download button post to the current window.location.
2. CodeIgniter has a [Download helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/download_helper.html) that does most of your PHP for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can download file after completing your ajax call then redirect to the file path.